# Getting result of child window to write to parent window

Tags: javascript, window, parent, addition

Im a beginner in Javascript and I am trying to get a result of a child window to write to the parent window. Here is the function from the child window:

function checkAnswer(){

```
var num1=parseInt(document.getElementById('firstNumber').value);
var num2=parseInt(document.getElementById('secondNumber').value);
var correctAnswer = num1+num2;
var userAnswer=parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);


if(userAnswer==correctAnswer){
window.opener.document.getElementById('input') = correctAnswer;
}

else{
alert('wrong');
}
```

}

I am trying to get the correctAnswer to appear on the parent window

Im not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am missing anything. Like I said, Im a beginner in Javascript and would appreciate the help :)

Comment: can you please put your code in jsfiddle. Issue doesn't seem to be in  window.opener.document.getElementById('input').value assignment.

Comment: the function works for me, if i change window.opener.document.getElementById('input').value assignment to alert('whatever') and I enter the right answer, it brings up the window. also works for me when I enter the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the problem

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('input') = correctAnswer;
```

It should be

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('input').value = correctAnswer;
```

Comment: It still didn't work.
I have <p id="input"></p> written on the parent window.
Also, the parent window is already open.

Comment: It is strange that you have a element (that is not an input) called input. If you want to make it work with a P or DIV or SPAN then use
window.opener.document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = correctAnswer;

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I had that before but I was using chrome to test.
Rookie mistake xD
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try innerHTML:

```
function checkAnswer() {
    var num1=parseInt(document.getElementById('firstNumber').value);
    var num2=parseInt(document.getElementById('secondNumber').value);
    var correctAnswer = num1+num2;
    var userAnswer=parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);

    if(userAnswer==correctAnswer){
        window.opener.document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = correctAnswer;
    }
    else{
       alert('wrong');
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1893388 Can you post you the html for your two pages?